# Navigation bar back button custom image y offset

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am putting custom back button image to the `UINavigationbar`.

```
func setBackButton()
{
    let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "BackButton")!
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -60), forBarMetrics: .Default)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.goldenColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImg
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImg
}
```

The custom image setup properly but the alignment is not appropriate. The y axis of back button is shift to lower y axis. How to align it to the middle of navigation bar.

My `back button image dimensions` are 34*9(1x), 68*18(2x), 135*36(3x)

[image]

Comment: usually the bar button will be align in the middle only i think the hight of the image is higher so it is displayed like this. Can you please provide the dimension of the image here

Comment: My back button image dimensions are 34*9(1x), 68*18(2x), 135*36(3x)

Comment: then try to set background colour for the back bar button then you can find the exact issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try set the back button as like follows,

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    [button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 0)];
else
    [button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
[button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 45);
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: I have to put the above code in all viewcontrollers. I want the custom back button in whole app. Thats why I am using UINavigationBar.appearance(). Any alternate?

Comment: you can create category for UIBarButton item implement the code there and call the method from all the view controllers so you can get the desired output. Or simple NSObject file put the code there and call it from all the viewController this will also gives the same output.

Comment: Is the above code working fine as you expected? If it is please mark it as a right answer.